# Normal temperature of a jigsaw

Tags: cutting, temperature, saw

I have a Makita 4329 jigsaw and I am wondering if the temperatures are normal or are a little high ?
I marked on the photo the temperatures that I feel with my hand when touching the mentioned part of the jigsaw. The temperatures from the photo were measured right after cutting continuously for about 5-10 minutes, with a few seconds pause from time to time. 
[image: Image1] 
Also, if I start the tool with no load (so without cutting), then it heats up a little less than the temperatures from the image.

Comment: That jigsaw looks brand new so welcome to DIY-ness! Yes the heat output is normal. Here are some things to consider. Extended periods of low speed use will cause issues because it won't allow the fan to cool things properly. Cutting particularly thick materials without rest like 1 inch steel or something will make it work very hard and can overheat it. Using a dull blade introduces unnecessary wear-n-tear on the tool. Aside from that, just use it as needed and don't baby it too much; it is a **power** tool after all not a weak tool :-)

Comment: That "hot" area is normal since it's directly connected to the cutting blade which would produce the most heat due to cutting friction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temperatures you're experiencing are normal for that type of saw. there will be little heat from the motor housing due to a fan fastened to the motor shaft for cooling, like a radiator fan in your car. The vent area does have warm air because that where the fan expels the heat from the motor and the gearbox. The vertical shaft holding the blade will be the warmest part of the saw with the exception of the blade when cutting. That's due to the constant friction of the shaft's up and down motion whether cutting of not. The gearbox for this motion is packed with grease but will still feel a little warm.